# Wait until function returns true

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

Does Dart have a method to wait for a function to return a true/false then call the next function after it?

I have seen similar questions here, but I cannot seem to get them to work in a way to achieve my goal.
Some of the answers use explicit delayed time (.e.g wait 3 seconds). But this doesn't work for my method.

E.g.

```
print('START');
await fetchResults(); 
print('COMPLETE'); // This is not called until the fetchResults returns true/false
```

NOTE: I have tried something like:

```
Future<bool> fetchResults() { 
   await Future.doWhile(() => return true);
}
```

But this puts my function in infinite loop.

Comment: `Future.doWhile` does what you want, but your attempt goes into an infinite loop because you passed a function that always returns `true`.  Use `await Future.doWhile(fetchResults);` to wait until `fetchResults()` returns `false`, or use `await Future.doWhile(() async => !await fetchResults());` to wait until it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look at what im doing wrong.

Comment: @jamesdlin My function uses an `EventChannel` that listens to change (Third party package). It is called using a function such `showScanner()`, but this doesnt give a callback, thus I am unable to do `then()`. So I have to find a way to change do my method. I assumed using a `Future await`, but this doesn't work (this is why i get infinite loop`.

Comment: I don't understand. 1. Taking a callback has nothing to do with `.then`.  To use `.then`, it must return a `Future`. 2. `await` is syntactic sugar for `.then`. 3. As I stated, you get an infinite loop because you used `Future.doWhile` with a function that always returns `true`.  It probably would help if you showed code that can reproduce the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications, after research it seems my problem was to do with `EventChannel`. This is where I must handle the events and the `wait` function is not required after all.

Answer (score 2):

In an `async` function you can use `await` to wait for a function call to be completed and get its result. This will wait 3 seconds before printing `COMPLETE`:

```dart
void waitForIt async {
  print('START');
  if (await (fetchResults())) {
    print('COMPLETE');
  }
}

Future<bool> fetchResults() async {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
    return true;
  });
}
```

But it is also possible that your `fetchResults` is not async, but sync. The following produces the same 3 seconds delay:

```
import 'dart:io';

bool fetchResults() {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I think there is misunderstanding, I do not want to use the time delay. I stated that, as that's the only answers I'm seeing online. My method work with time as it can work there is no defined delay, except through a boolean.

Comment: It is just to simulate a real-world fetch that would take time to complete. Examples use this often. If you provide more details maybe I can help.

Comment: How is that boolean value received?

Comment: I am using a third part package, which doesn't return a callback or allow any parameters. But it handles the completion somewhere else within `.receiveBroadcastStream().listen()`, this is where an explicit function is called, and I can change the boolean value here. The `showScanner()` can be called anywhere. The reason I do not want to use specific time, is because it gives result after the scanner is closed or scans successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two async function for that

```
Future<void> execute()async {
  print('START');
  final result = await fetchResults(); 
  print('COMPLETE'); // This is not called until the fetchResults returns true/false
}
```

```
Future<bool> fetchResults() async { 

   // Your fetchResult logic here
   // e.g: 

   final int result = 1+1;
   print('In between'); 
   if(result == 2) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Output

```
START
In between
COMPLETE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill test this.